# Apache2 re-install error

Tags: installation, apt, apache2, dpkg

I am trying to re-install apache2 on my Ubntu12.X machine. I had apache2 before but due some reasons I have uninstalled.

I use `apt-get purge` to remove apache tomcat
but while re installing I am getting these error.
I have tried many way explained in many blogs, none of the could solve my issue.

```
Setting up apache2.2-common (2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4) ...
ERROR: Config file dir.conf not properly enabled: /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf is a real file, not touching it
dpkg: error processing apache2.2-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apache2-mpm-worker:
 apache2-mpm-worker depends on apache2.2-common (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4); however:
  Package apache2.2-common is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing apache2-mpm-worker (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apache2:
 apache2 depends on apache2-mpm-worker (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4) | apache2-mpm-prefork (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4) | apache2-mpm-event (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4) | apache2-mpm-itk (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4); however:
  Package apache2-mpm-worker is not configured yet.
  Package apache2-mpm-prefork is not installed.
  Package apache2-mpm-event is not installed.
  Package apache2-mpm-itk is not installed.
 apache2 depends on apache2.2-common (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4); however:
  Package apache2.2-common is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing apache2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apache2.2-common
 apache2-mpm-worker
 apache2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: have you tried to manually delete this dir.conf file?

Comment: I deleted. now seems like its working. Thanks!!!

Comment: Does it works ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove and reinstall `apache2.2-common`,`apache2-mpm-worker`,`apache2` packages by running,

```
sudo dpkg -P apache2.2-common
sudo dpkg -P apache2-mpm-worker
sudo dpkg -P apache2
```

Reinstall the above by running,

```
sudo apt-get install apache2.2-common
sudo apt-get install apache2-mpm-worker
sudo apt-get install apache2
```